# CSS flexbox SASS mixin that supports no flexbox legacy

Tags: css, internet-explorer, sass, flexbox

Is there a way to support browsers with no flexbox legacy(IE) within the use of SASS mixins?

I'm using below a mixin for implementing `display:flex` rapidly. Though I have some issues with IE, since I do have to target every  class that I'ved used the mixin to switch it to `display:table`and `display:table-cell` using [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/), since `display:flex` is not fully supported on some browsers.

```
@mixin flexbox() {
    display: -webkit-box !important;
    display: -moz-box !important;
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    display: -webkit-flex !important;
    display: flex !important;
}
```

Is there anyway I can do a conditioning on my mixin if its inside a `body` with a class of `flexboxlegacy` or `no-flexboxlegacy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@mixin flexbox() {
  display: flex;

  .no-flexboxlegacy & {
    display: table;
  }
}

a b c {
  @include flexbox();
}
```

Compiles to:

```
a b c {
  display: flex;
}

.no-flexboxlegacy a b c {
  display: table;
}
```